# Detect when a component is no longer in use

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jpanel, observer-pattern, toolkit

I've written a component (JPanel) which is used in a larger project I don't have control over. My component can be instantiated and closed at the whim of the user, but I don't get notified when it's about to close. The problem is I'm subscribing to some events:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(this, AWTEvent.WINDOW_EVENT_MASK);
```

Ideally I would like to deregister from those events when my component is no longer used.

Question 1) I assume my component won't get GC'ed until it has unsubscribed from the toolkit - is that a correct?

Question 2) Is there some way I can check if my component is no longer in use? (to be notified would be nice, but polling might be okay)

Comment: I'm missing something. If you wrote the component, can't you add a listener to it which will notify you for whatever it is you want?

Comment: My component is being loaded by an application I don't control. It would be nice if I could modify that application, in which case I would be able to call a close() method on my control

Comment: I still don't understand. You can add a listener to your component that when it is closed will perform some action, like deregistering or sending a notification.

Comment: Thanks 1803, what listener can I add to my component?

Comment: A [Window Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html).